# Add style to outer div of Angular selectors by conditions

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, styles

I have three components which creates a hierarchy structure like this:

```
<div>c1 is the root</div>
|
 ------ c2 is inisde c1
         |
          -------- c3 is inisde c2
```

How can I add style to the specific div which consists of c2 > c3 in specific order?

Comment: Doesn't help you using ```class``` for each component separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add condition styles as below:

(1) [style] option

```
<div [style.color]="c1Condition ? 'red' : 'black' ">
     c1 is the root
     <div [style.color]="c2Condition ? 'red' : 'black' ">
          c2 is inisde c1
          <div [style.color]="c2Condition ? 'red' : 'black' ">
               c3 is inisde c2
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

(2) [ngStyle]  in .html file

```
<div [ngStyle]="currentStyles1">
   Hello World
</div>
```

and in component.ts

```
this.currentStyles1 = {     
       'font-style':  this.canSave  ? 'italic' : 'normal',  
       'color':       this.hasError ? 'red'   : 'black',     
       'font-size':   this.hasError ? '24px'   : '12px'   
};
```

(3) [ngClass] option

```
<div [ngClass]="false ? 'c_on' : 'c_off'">Hello world! </div>
```

Comment: But this is typically to angular. Is there any option with raw css?

Comment: @JanTestowy - you mean just .html .css? this seems way old school approach.
If you are using Angular than I would recommend to use angular way conditional styles.